# How to scan VPN with Nmap

Tags: vpn, nmap

I have Zenmap installed on my Windows machine. How can I scan my VPN network? The command I use is:

```
nmap -T4 -A -v 192.168.0.1-255
```

But It is quitting with error:

```
WARNING: Using raw sockets because ppp0 is not an ethernet device. This probably won't work on Windows.

pcap_open_live(ppp0, 100, 0, 2) FAILED. Reported error: Error opening adapter: The system cannot find the device specified. (20).  Will wait 5 seconds then retry.

pcap_open_live(ppp0, 100, 0, 2) FAILED. Reported error: Error opening adapter: The system cannot find the device specified. (20).  Will wait 25 seconds then retry.

Call to pcap_open_live(ppp0, 100, 0, 2) failed three times. Reported error: Error opening adapter: The system cannot find the device specified. (20)

QUITTING!
```

Answer (score 3):

you must add -e eth0

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Have you [installed WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm)?

You may need this on Windows as the OS does not natively handle raw sockets.